# Yet again another problem with an Intel Wireless Driver

Tags: 16.04, networking, drivers, intel-wireless

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 on a Toshiba Satellite L50-B for months now and in the last week it became unable to connect to wi-fi. I scanned the internet and tried a lot of the solutions proposed but nothing seemed to fix the problem.

The general state of affairs is that the wi-fi driver is not working, apparently. When checking the status bar I see "Wifi Networks - disconnected" and generally cannot see the available wifi networks, even though my phone is on one.

My Network controller is the Intel Corporation Wireless 3160 (rev 83). I tried downloading the driver and copying it into /lib/framework but didn't work.

The bluetooth is off, so that shouldn't be the issue. Can you help me please?

I also ran `modinfo iwlwifi` but the result is too long to post in here. A part of it (without the aliases) is here:

```
filename:       /lib/modules/4.13.0-39-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/iwlwifi.ko
license:        GPL
author:         Copyright(c) 2003- 2015 Intel Corporation <linuxwifi@intel.com>
description:    Intel(R) Wireless WiFi driver for Linux
firmware:       iwlwifi-100-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-1000-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-135-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-105-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-2030-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-2000-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-5150-2.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-5000-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2b-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2a-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6050-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7265D-29.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7265-17.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-3168-29.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-3160-17.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7260-17.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-8265-33.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-8000C-33.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-9260-th-b0-jf-b0--33.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-9260-th-a0-jf-a0--33.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-9000-pu-a0-jf-b0--33.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-9000-pu-a0-jf-a0--33.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-Qu-a0-jf-b0--33.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-Qu-a0-hr-a0--33.ucode
srcversion:     339D7D3BD0DD2A9C7FE616F
depends:        cfg80211
intree:         Y
name:           iwlwifi
vermagic:       4.13.0-39-generic SMP mod_unload 
parm:           swcrypto:using crypto in software (default 0 [hardware]) (int)
parm:           11n_disable:disable 11n functionality, bitmap: 1: full, 2: disable agg TX, 4: disable agg RX, 8 enable agg TX (uint)
parm:           amsdu_size:amsdu size 0: 12K for multi Rx queue devices, 4K for other devices 1:4K 2:8K 3:12K (default 0) (int)
parm:           fw_restart:restart firmware in case of error (default true) (bool)
parm:           antenna_coupling:specify antenna coupling in dB (default: 0 dB) (int)
parm:           nvm_file:NVM file name (charp)
parm:           d0i3_disable:disable d0i3 functionality (default: Y) (bool)
parm:           lar_disable:disable LAR functionality (default: N) (bool)
parm:           uapsd_disable:disable U-APSD functionality bitmap 1: BSS 2: P2P Client (default: 3) (uint)
parm:           bt_coex_active:enable wifi/bt co-exist (default: enable) (bool)
parm:           led_mode:0=system default, 1=On(RF On)/Off(RF Off), 2=blinking, 3=Off (default: 0) (int)
parm:           power_save:enable WiFi power management (default: disable) (bool)
parm:           power_level:default power save level (range from 1 - 5, default: 1) (int)
parm:           fw_monitor:firmware monitor - to debug FW (default: false - needs lots of memory) (bool)
parm:           d0i3_timeout:Timeout to D0i3 entry when idle (ms) (uint)
parm:           disable_11ac:Disable VHT capabilities (default: false) (bool)
```

Comment: Did you upgrade your kernel recently by any chance?